# obtain mysqli_stmt_execute() return value before executing query

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

```
if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) && send_mail($email)) {
    //operation was successful
}
else {
    //something went wrong
}
```

After user inputted his values, I want to insert them into a database table and send an email to user. In this piece of code if `mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)` and `send_mail($email)` both be true everything is good, but if one of them be false there are two problems here:
1. if `mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)` be false, then user receives an email, but his record hasn't been inserted into the database.
2.if `send_mail($email)` be false, user's record inserts into the database, but email that is for  activating his account hasn't been sent to him.
please help me solve this problem.

Comment: first, if mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) be false, send_mail will not be executed.  Second problem, you could use database transaction.

Comment: database transaction is the answer, thanks.